# Control Enable and disable of controls using form group angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i am new in angular 2 and i have the following question:
i have a form written in Angular 2. 
The form contains several controls.
The controls depends on each other.
For example:

[Example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT5PD.png)

if radioButton1 selected then show option1, option2, option3 in the next lavel.
or if radioButton2 selected then show option3, option4, option5 in the next lavel.
and if radioButton1 and opetion2 selected then show option 6 in third lavel. etc.

what is the best way to do it in Angular2? Can i use FormGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NgSwitch.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

```
<div>//radio button group</div>
<div [ngSwitch]="radiomodelvalue">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="value1">//option group 1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="value2">//option group 2</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="value3">//option group 3</div>
 <div *ngSwitchDefault></div>
</div>
```